# Create a bar chart from CSV

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, csv

I have a `.csv` file that looks like this:

```
gender.csv

GENDER,NUMBER,PERCENT
MALE,20,20
FEMALE,80,80
TOTAL,100,100
```

I want to create a bar chart using *MALE* and *FEMALE*.

*GENDER* can be the chart name or the axis name and I don't want the **total** to be shown.

I have been trying with `pgfplot`.

I have been stuck for hours on this, can you help me please.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem also. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you please add your code of your efforts? It would help the solvers a lot.